# Hesto multi-auth guard is not redirecting where page was before after login

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I am on page : `http://laravel.dev/lists`

which shows me list of item

```
<a href="http://laravel.dev/lists/1">Item 1</a>
<a href="http://laravel.dev/lists/2">Item 1</a>
<a href="http://laravel.dev/lists/3">Item 1</a>
```

but above item can only accessible to authorized user

**Issue**

when i click on `Item 1` so if user is not logged in then it goes to `http://laravel.dev/login` then user proceed to login but after login it must redirect to `http://laravel.dev/lists/1` but it is redirecting to `http://laravel.dev/home`.

**I have tried**

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    session()->put('url.intended',url()->previous());

    // or 

    session()->put('url.intended', url()->current());

    return view('user.auth.login');
}
```

but above is not working, it is redirecting to `http://laravel.dev/lists`

laravel own auth is working fine.

but hesto multi-auth is not working

I am using this [Hesto-multi-auth](https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth) package for multiple authentication like `admin, user, employee`

is there any solution for this

Comment: What's the  version of Laravel you used?

Comment: i am using Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default user Authentication system in Laravel, and if you added `auth` middleware in your routes, it's automatically done by Laravel.

In your `routes`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    . . . Your Routes goes Here
});
```

You can take a look at the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#protecting-routes

Comment: suppose you have two domain `admin.website.com` and default is `website.com` so there is two type user one is admin and other is public user and both are managed by different table or database so how can i achieve this.

Comment: You can assign multiple middleware in routes

`Routes::group(['middleware' => ['public', 'admin']], function() { . . . Routes Here });

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware. For example :

```
Route::get('lists/{id}', function () {
    //
})->middleware('auth');
```

Please refer here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware for more information

Comment: I am using a guard() for multiple authentication. have a look on package which i am using.

Answer (score 0):

First of all find the place where you redirect unauthenticated user to the login page (probably in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` `function unauthenticated`) and save to the session current url ("/lists/1") before redirect.

Afrer that add in your Auth controller property `$redirectTo` and fill it from the session or define method `redirectTo` (method also nust return url).
Out of the box laravel redirects to `/home` because of trait `/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RedirectsUsers`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this idea: *After you've successfully logged in, you'll be redirected to the page you want (e.g. http://laravel.dev/lists/1)*

```
Auth::attempt(...);

return redirect()->route('the name of your route here where redirected to http://laravel.dev/lists/1');
```

Answer (score 0):

What you had tried in the `showLoginForm()` won't be work, because neither `url()->previous()` nor `url()->current()` you specified were not the url you want.

**Solution:**
Changed in the middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'user')
{
    if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        session()->put('url.intended', \URL::current()); // Add this line
        return redirect('user/login');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: there is two middleware `RedirectIfNotAdmin.php` and `RedirectIfAdmin.php` and i have used above in `RedirectIfNotAdmin.php`